# HttpClient what and for what?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient

What is HttpClient? For what it is? From what I need to start write simple http client for api controllers? I need it to get simple access to contollers.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

Comment: This is [easily Googleable](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=asp.net+httpclient+example&oq=asp.net+httpclient+example&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30j0i8.953.2000.0.2125.8.8.0.0.0.0.188.968.1j6.7.0...0.0...1c.1.7.serp.nLtOJZOCWVc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a start:

```
private Order SendOrderRequest(Models.OrderTest model)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(model.BaseUrl + "order");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = uri;

    var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

    HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Order>(model.Order, jsonFormatter);
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

    return responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Supertext.API.POCO.Order)).Result as Supertext.API.POCO.Order;
}
```

It just posts the order object inside the model to a Web API (and gets an order object back)

Comment: Great, what about marking my answer as correct now?